# conversion from text to int is not supported error

Tags: sql, sql-server

ı work on sql server management studio , ı   accidentally defined nvarchar type id column  ,when ı wanted change to int type ,ı get this error. What is the solution to this error?

Comment: What is the error message and are you sure the field does not have alphabets in it?

Comment: Fix the data. You have at least one value that is unable to convert to an int.